# How to get pages of parent (non-recursive)?

Tags: wp-query, pages

I'd like to get all pages that are direct children of HOME_ID. Per http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages#Parameters (see 'parent' parameter), I think this should be done with get_pages:

```
$top_pages = get_pages(array('parent' => HOME_ID, 'sort_column' => 'menu_order'));
```

but this returns no results. I get results back if I plug in 0 for HOME_ID. No sweat because I can achieve what I want with:

```
$menu_wp_query = new WP_Query();
$top_pages = $menu_wp_query->query(array('post_type' => 'page', 'post_parent' => HOME_ID, 'orderby' => 'menu_order'));
```

But still uncomfortable; is this a bug? Using WP 3.2.1 Thanks.

Comment: have u noticed that parent is an integer value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that, by "HOME_ID", you are referring to the **static Page used to display the Site Front Page**, then you want to use `get_option( 'front_page' )` to get the **ID** for this page:

```
<?php
$menu_wp_query_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'page', 
    'post_parent' => get_option( 'front_page' ), 
    'orderby' => 'menu_order'
);
$new_wp_query = new WP_Query( $new_wp_query_args );
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your homepage has title as 'Home'. Use this:

```
<?php

$home = get_page_by_title('Home');
$home_children = get_posts(array('post_type'=>'page', 'post_parent'=>$home->ID));

echo "<pre>";
print_r($home_children);
echo "</pre>";    

?>
```

Make sure you pass the exact title to the get_page_by_title function.

Answer (score 0):

in a custom template Page i use

query_posts(array( 'post_parent' => 6, 'post_type' => 'page'));

post_parent is selected by ID of the specific Page, in this case 6.
..at least it works for me.
Hope that helps.
cheers!

Comment: **Do not use `query_posts()` for secondary loop queries.**